# How to display image using AWS S3 and Vapor 3 and Leaf

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vapor, leaf

I have set up AWS S3 bucket and I'm able to upload files there using Vapor 3 and Postman. I can also get files using Vapor 3 and Postman but I have a hard time to get and actually display files(png -images) on my browser (I'm using leaf).

So how can I display image files on the view? I'm new with HTML, AWS S3 and Vapor.

I'm using:

- Vapor 3
- AWS S3
- Leaf package
- S3 package
- VaporExt package

I followed this tutorial to set up everything (except the get request and the bucket policies): https://fivedottwelve.com/blog/using-amazon-s3-with-vapor/

Here are my Vapor code:

```swift
/// GET reguest
func preparePresignedImageUrl(request: Request) throws -> String {

    let baseUrl = awsConfig.url
    let imagePath = awsConfig.imagePath
    let fileName = "x.png"


    guard var url = URL(string: baseUrl) else {
        throw Abort(.internalServerError)
    }
    url.appendPathComponent(imagePath)
    url.appendPathComponent(fileName)

    print("url is \(url)")
    let headers = ["x-amz-acl" : "public-read"]


    let s3 = try request.makeS3Signer()
    let result = try s3.presignedURL(for: .GET, url: url, expiration: Expiration.hour, headers: headers)
    /// Retrieve file data from S3

    guard let presignedUrl = result?.absoluteString else {
        throw Abort(.internalServerError)
    }

    return presignedUrl

}
```

The route:

```swift
// GET request
 group.get("aws", "image", use: preparePresignedImageUrl)
```

And in the Postman when I make a GET request to that `presignedURL` it gives me a status code 200OK.

My `showImage.leaf` file:

```html
#set("content") {
<h1>#(title)</h1>

// Here some html to get the image path and display the image?
  <img>

}

#embed("base")
```

Comment: Share the `Future<View>` related code for `showImage.leaf` and the context model you are is using, i.e. the one that allows you to use `#(title)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am going to assume that you have a perfectly good URL to the image.

Let's start by creating a route at `GET /image`:

```swift
routes.get("image", use: image)

func image(_ request: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<View> {

}
```

To properly render the Leaf view, we will need a context that contains the data for the Leaf variables. It will look something like this:

```swift
struct ImageContext: Encodable {
    let title: String
    let imageURL: String
}
```

We also need to edit your leaf file so it will use the properties in the context:

```
#set("content") {
<h1>#(title)</h1>
<img src="#(imageURL)">
}

#embed("base")
```

Now we can render the leaf file with out new context and return the resulting view from the route handler. Here is what the implementation of the `image` route handler will look like:

```swift
func image(_ request: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<View> {
    let context = ImageContext(title: "Image", imageURL: preparePresignedImageUrl(request: request)
    return try request.view().make("showImage", context)
}
```

Now you should be able to access `localhost:8080/image` from your browser and the image will be there!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm trying to make it work to the opposite direcction and posted a new question. Could you please help me with that? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372209/how-to-upload-images-from-the-browser-to-amazon-s3-using-vapor-and-leaf)